# The slope of the tangent line

Tags: integration, limits, functions

I don't know how to solve these three, especially the first and the second one:

$1.$ $x=0$ means upper limit also equal to $0$? what should I do to deal with the $(t^2+\pi^2)^{1/2}$?

$2.$ Find the anti-derivative?

$3.$ Just have messed up different concept, please give me some sort of hints.

Thanks.

it would be so nice if anyone help me or give me hints :)

1. Find the slope of the tangent line of $y=\displaystyle \int_0^x\sin\sqrt{t^2+\pi^2}\ \mathrm{d}t$ at$\ x=0$
2. Find the total area enclosed by $y=x^2-4x+3$, the $x$-axis and the $y$-axis, treating all area portions as non-negative.
   [image: second]
   [image: the original]

is it valid?

Comment: It would be even nicer if you showed us any attempts you made.  People will be more inclined to help you if they see you've put some effort into this. :-)

Answer (score 1):

**1.**
Considering the $y$ as a function of $x$, we have that
\begin{align}
y(x) = \int_0^x \text{sin}\sqrt{t^2+\pi^2}dt.
\end{align}
And from that we see can see that
\begin{align}
y'(x)=\text{sin} \sqrt{x^2+\pi^2}, \text{so}\\y'(0)=\text{sin}\sqrt{0^2+\pi^2} = \text{sin}\pi = 0.
\end{align}
So the slope of $y(x)$ at $x=0$, $y'(0)$ is zero.

**2.** EDIT: The question seems different from when I answered it before.
Let
\begin{align}
f(x)= x^2-4x+3,
\end{align}
then the area you need to compute is the area that is placed to the left of $f(x)$, to the right of the $y$-axis and above the $x$-axis (*again, see a plot: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2-4x%2B3*).

Since the function is greater than zero in that area, the integral will already be positive, so we do not have to worry about treating the area as non-negative. You correctly found the first root to be at $x=1$. The area is then
\begin{align}
\int_0^1f(x)dx &= \left[ \frac{1}{3}x^3 -2x^2+3x \right]_{x=0}^1\\
&=\left(\frac{1}{3}\cdot1^3-2\cdot1^2+3\cdot1\right)-\left(\frac{1}{3}\cdot0^3-2\cdot0^2+3\cdot0\right)\\
&=\left(\frac{1}{3}-2+3\right)-0\\
&=\frac{4}{3}.
\end{align}
Let's check if this answer makes sense. The area should be slightly lower than that of the right triangle with vertices $(0,0)$, $(1,0)$, and $(0,3)$. This area is
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2}\cdot\text{Base Line}\cdot \text{Height} = \frac{1}{2}\cdot1\cdot3=\frac{3}{2}.
\end{align}
Since $\frac{3}{2}=1.5$ is slightly higher than $\frac{4}{3}=1.333...$, the answer makes sense.

Comment: thank you, but there's only one function in question 2.

Comment: f(x)=x^2-4x+3=(x-3)(x-1),x=3,x=1.  so what should i do to calculate the portions as non-negative?

Comment: The answer equal to 4/3